# How to fix TypeScript function type error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have TypeScript code:

```
const ItemsList: React.FC<any> = async () => {
  const data = await Http.get(url);
  return (
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => {
          return (
            <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item} />
          );
        })}
      </ul>
  )
}

export default ItemsList
```

And got error:
Type '()=>Promise<JSX.Element>' is not assingable to type 'FC'. Type 'Promise' is missing the folowing properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Have no idea how to fix it. What type should it be instead of 'React.FC'?

Comment: No, you cant have `async` react functional component. Marking function as `async` makes it always return a `Promise`

Comment: You won't make it usable by fixing types. Google for "data fetching in react component".

Comment: ```Http.get(url)``` return promise. So if i can't use async how can I get data?  :( Any idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're effectively thinking about it the wrong way.  Instead of trying to make React component rendering *wait* for your data, instead you should be thinking of it in terms of updating state in React.  Your component should just render whatever the current state is:

```
return (
  <ul>
    {data.map(item => {
      return (
        <ItemPreview key={item.id} item={item} />
      );
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

Now, what is `data`?  Clearly it's an array, and you also have an asynchronous operation which gets the values for that array.  So currently there are a couple potential states:

1. An initial empty array
2. The updated array with data

You'd use React state to track that.  For example:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

Http.get(url).then(result => {
  setData(result);
});
```

This first sets `data` to an empty array, and then in the response from the asynchronous operation updates it to the new data.  Since it's using `setState`, this will instruct React to update the rendering of the component because state has changed.

So in this case the UI will first show no results, then momentarily will show the data.  You can add complexity to this by tracking an "is loading" state of some kind and showing a "loading spinner" or some indication to the user that data is being fetched.